# How can I disable the program unclutter without remove its package?

Tags: apt, package-management, systemd, services, unclutter

On my lubuntu 22.04 I have installed the package `unclutter` by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install unclutter
```

A description of this package is the following:

> unclutter hides your X mouse cursor when you don’t need it, to prevent it from getting in the way. You have only to move the mouse to restore the mouse cursor.

After the installation and the reboot I could see the following `unclutter` process by `ps aux`:

```
$ ps aux | grep unclutter
myuser  926  0.0  0.1   4704  2784 ?  S    09:39   0:00 /usr/bin/unclutter -idle 1 -root
```

Furthermore by `systemctl status` I can suppose that `unclutter` has been started by `systemd` because the output of the command `systemctl status` contains:

```
$ systemctl status

├─user.slice 
|       ├─user-1000.slice 
|       │   ├─user@1000.service
|       |   ...
|       └─session-1.scope 
|          │     ├─ ...
|          │     ├─ ...
|          │     ├─ 926 /usr/bin/unclutter -idle 1 -root
...       ...    ...
```

#### unclutter-startup

By the command `apt list --installed` I have found that, with `unclutter`, is also installed the package `unclutter-startup`, and in [the documentation](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/unclutter-startup) the description of this other package is:

> autostart infrastructure for unclutter and unclutter-xfixes

This sentence explains that `unclutter`, by the package `unclutter-startup`, has an *autostart infrastructure* which is responsible of it startup.

#### My question

Probably the program `unclutter` is started by a service, but I can't understand what is the service which starts it. So how can I disable `unclutter` without remove the package?

Comment: What does `systemctl status <pid-of-unclutter>` show?

Comment: @muru I think that the most important info which `systemctl status <pid-of-unclutter>` shows are: 1) `session-1.scope`, 2) `Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/session-1.scope; transient)` 3) `CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope`

Comment: Then it's not started by systemd, but by some other mechanism. Probably XDG autostart. According to [the file list of `unclutter-startup`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/unclutter-startup/filelist), I'd say that's the `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter` script.

Comment: @muru Thank you very much. I have found the solution. I'll write an answer to share it.

Comment: Actually I can disable `unclutter` by the file `/etc/default/unclutter` and not directly by the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the help of @muru I have found the solution for my question.

#### The file `/etc/default/unclutter`

By the file `/etc/default/unclutter` is possible to select if to start `unclutter` after X has been started and so it is possible to disable its start.

The content of the file `/etc/default/unclutter` is the following:

```
# /etc/default/unclutter - configuration file for unclutter

# Set this option to 'true' if you want to start unclutter
# automagically after X has been started for a user.
# Otherwise, set it to 'false'.
START_UNCLUTTER="true"

# Options passed to unclutter, see 'man unclutter' for details.
EXTRA_OPTS="-idle 1 -root"
```

As we can read in the comments, to disable the start of `unclutter` I have to set the value of the variable `START_UNCLUTTER` to `"false"`:

```
START_UNCLUTTER="false"
```

#### Restart display manager

After made the previous change value I have to restart the display manager by the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart display-manager
```

without need of reboot.

#### `systemd` is not involved

As explained by @muru with this comment:

> Then it's not started by systemd, but by some other mechanism. Probably XDG autostart. According to the [file list of unclutter-startup](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/unclutter-startup/filelist), I'd say that's the `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter` script.

`systemd` is not involved in the `unclutter` startup.